# Interact with component in component

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a button component, which I'm using in my own component. Works fine so far.

This button has a property boolean of 'loading' that determines if a spinner is shown. My question is now, how can I from my method link to this button component and change the property of loading to true?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button-component></button-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ButtonComponent from 'ButtonComponent';

  export default {
    components: {
      ButtonComponent
    },
    methods: {
      buttonClick() {
        // Set loading to true
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways you could do it, I think the easiest is to use `v-ref`:

`<button-component v-ref:loading-button></button-component>`

```
    methods: {
      buttonClick() {
        this.$refs.loadingButton.loading = true;
      }
    }
```

Or you could add a loading property to the parent and sync it:

`<button-component :loading.sync="loading"></button-component>`

```
    data:{
        loading: false,
    },
    methods: {
      buttonClick() {
        this.loading = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The v-ref was the solution I was looking for!